# Dynamically change the tab control header in TFS

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to change the header of tab control based on the area path selected?
For example, if area path X is selected, i want the tab headers to be U,V,W
if Y is selected, i want tab headers to be A,B,C

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible.

If you are on VSTS, or can wait for TFS 2015 Update 3, then you can use the extension model to create it yourself:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/extensions/overview